# About $T(n,k)=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}+\frac{1}{(n+2)!}+\frac{1}{(n+3)!}+...+\frac{1}{(n+k)!}$ where $n,k\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences, exponential-sum

For $n,k\in \mathbb{N}$ let $$T(n,k)=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}+\frac{1}{(n+2)!}+\frac{1}{(n+3)!}+...+\frac{1}{(n+k)!}$$

Which of the below statement(s) hold true

(A)$T(n,k)\geq \frac{1}{2}$

(B)$T(n,k)> \frac{1}{(n-1)!}$

**My Attempt**

I am trying to create a geometric progression
$T(n,k)=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}+\frac{1}{(n+2)!}+\frac{1}{(n+3)!}+...+\frac{1}{(n+k)!}<\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+...$

but am not getting anywhere

Comment: Neither necessarily hold true. Try $k=1$ for $n \ge 2$.

Comment: Take the smallest term in the sum and multiply it by number of items in the sum. You get one inequality if you estimate expression of the form $k/(n+k )$.